# Creating a stylus holder that attaches to tablet via full sized USB

Tags: technology, organization, plastics

This is basically what I want for my windows tablet to hold my wacom stylus:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yco2f.png

My tablet is maybe 2-3 mm thicker than the height of a USB port so the above pic won't do- its base is too fat and I'd prefer attachment via USB rather than adhesion.

**Has someone already made something like this? What would be the easiest way to achieve my idea for someone who has no rubber/metal or 3d printing materials and can't build anything on his own?**

Anyway to jerryrig what I want to make with some common household items and perhaps some kind of strong adhesive? I don't want to use the average sized flashdrive- its too long and sticks out of the tablet too much. **Are there any USB flashdrives that go parallel to the side of the tablet instead of perpendicular?**

This below may work as a platform to hold the pen loop/pen claw but I don't know where to find a secure pen loop or attach it
[http://www.amazon.com/HDE-SuperSpeed-Vertical-Adapter-Connector/dp/B00KQV1BXI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451469043&sr=8-1&keywords=90+degree+flash+drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KQV1BXI)

This is my stylus: It's fatter than a pencil but maybe slightly thinner than some pens
[http://www.amazon.com/Fujitsu-Digitizer-replacement-Stylus-T5000/dp/B00791UTH2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451469190&sr=8-1&keywords=fujitsu+lifebook+stylus#Ask](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00791UTH2)

Answer (score 1):

I like your idea of using the USB adapter as a platform for loop or claw to hold the stylus.

I have used hand mold-able thermoplastic for similar purposes. They come in several brand names like InstaMorph, Polymorph etc. Basically it is a plastic with low melting point that you can soften with hot water and use your hand to mold it into the desired shape. This plastic is re-usable and can thus be re-done if the design doesn't work. I would suggest using the USB connector you linked to and then use the plastic to make a loop or any shape that would hold the stylus. The plastic sets hard and is a bit flexible, so you could make a claw with a small opening to hold the stylus.

There is another material called 'Sugru' that is essentially a silicone putty that sets into a hard flexible material, but is not re-usable. Search for it and you will see a lot of interesting uses for it.

For those of us who don't have access to a 3D printer, these materials are perfect for quick hacks.

Comment: Also, a less permanent but reusable alternative to 'Sugru' would be 'Blu-Tack'.